# Loading images in background to optimize the loading in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, lazy-loading

I am trying to optimize the load in my application, in fact, I have a lot of images that loaded in my application, and I spend a lot of time waiting for a view controller to open, especially the first initial view which includes a lot of images.

I took a look at [apple sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

but I cannot re-work the whole application, what I want is just to tell me specifically what should I do?, I implement?

in the `tableview`, where the cell is implemented `cellforrowatindexpath:`

```
 NSURL *imageURL = ......;
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
 UIImage *imageLoad;
 imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
 imageView.image = imageLoad;
```

could I do something?

thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]; will take long..try async loading of images

Comment: can you write it as code? please tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add **placeholder** image to it.

It will not slow down the scrolling and will load image accordingly with time.

Also **import** this file **UIImageView+WebCache.m** and **MapKit** Framework

[Here is the link](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.m) to download the files.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
    UIImageview*  iV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
   [iV setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_placeholder.gif"]];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:iV];
   [iV release];

}
```

Just **clean, build and run.**

Comment: i will try and give u a feedback

Comment: **Add complete folder in your project** and just **#import"UIImageView+WebCache.h"** file in the file in which you are loading images in `UITableview`.

Comment: when I try to copy the whole folder, I check the (copy items into destination's groups if needed), but when I run the application, an error occurred which is : SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKAnnotationView", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_MKAnnotationView_$_WebCache in MKAnnotationView+WebCache.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).........

Comment: should I create each file by myself??? or there is a method to import them right?

Comment: Have you added all the files in the xcode project? All the files should appear in the left pannel of the xcode.

Comment: I added it, and i add imageIO framework also, now the run works, still i have to test is the problem of images loading is resolved or not

Comment: look, I am very happy, and thanks alot, it works, thannnnnkkkkk youuuuuuuu

Answer (score 6):

Try this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    /* Fetch the image from the server... */
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        /* This is the main thread again, where we set the tableView's image to
         be what we just fetched. */
        cell.imgview.image = img;
    });
});
```

Comment: i will try and give u a feedback

Comment: I tried your solution for an image viewer in a project. Works fine! Just wanted to add it then also for lazy loading of thumbnails in UITableViewCells and a little problem appeared: The UIImage *img is not visible inside the block that calls the main thread. Will give it a research!

Comment: I found an easy solution to make the var visible in the other blog dispatches on the main queue. I will add it as a new answer and post my edited code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this control:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

It's very easy to implement (only 1 header file) and will suit your needs just fine.

Using this control:
Instead of declaring:

```
NSURL *imageURL = ......;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *imageLoad;
imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
imageView.image = imageLoad;
```

Use:

```
NSURL *imageURL = ......;
imageView.imageURL = imageURL;
```

Comment: i will try and give u a feedback

Answer (score 2):

To enable the app while getting the images from server and disable block while loading the images try to use **UIImageView+AFNetworking** library to load the image from server asynchronously [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
   NSString *imageUrl = [[dict objectForKey:@"photo"] objectForKey:@"url"];

   UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

   [myImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"PlaceHolder.png"]];
```

Just add this library and include the UIImageView+AFNetworking so you can use the new UIImageView Category **imageWithUrl**

Comment: i will try and give u a feedback

Comment: when I adding the library, i check the (copy items into destination's groups if needed), but when I run it, an error appeared: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).........
should I create each file from this library by myself? or there is a method to import it into my application?

Answer (score 2):

you can check this tutorial on [NSOperationQueue](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) and this on [GCD](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) doing exactly same. Also you can try using:

```
// Block variable to be assigned in block.
__block NSData *imageData;
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue  = dispatch_queue_create("com.razeware.imagegrabber.bgqueue", NULL);

// Dispatch a background thread for download
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *imageLoad;
    imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    // Update UI on main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        imageView.image = imageLoad;
    });
});
```

Comment: i will try and give u a feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this!....

```
 dispatch_queue_t checkInQueueForPostImage = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

                        dispatch_async(checkInQueueForPostImage, ^{
                            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postAndCheckInDetails.postImageURL]]];

                            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                if (image!=nil) {
                                    [uploadImage setImage:image];
                                }

                                [cell setNeedsLayout];
                            });
                        });
```

Comment: i will try and give u a feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can use async imageview.

```
- (void) loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url placeholderImage:(UIImage*)placeholder cachingKey:(NSString*)key {
    self.imageURL = url;
    self.image = placeholder;

    NSData *cachedData = [FTWCache objectForKey:key];
    if (cachedData) {   
       self.imageURL   = nil;
       self.image      = [UIImage imageWithData:cachedData];
       return;
    }

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        UIImage *imageFromData = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        [FTWCache setObject:data forKey:key];

        if (imageFromData) {
            if ([self.imageURL.absoluteString isEqualToString:url.absoluteString]) {
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.image = imageFromData;
                });
            } else {
//              NSLog(@"urls are not the same, bailing out!");
            }
        }
        self.imageURL = nil;
    });
}
```

Take a look at [this link](https://gist.github.com/khanlou/4998479).You will have an idea on using async imageview.

Comment: i will try and give u a feedback

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified approach of Ramu Pasupoletis answer. I added the
    __block
modifier to make the var img visible inside the block called on the main thread. Here is the complete method definition which I use in

```
-(UITableViewCell*)cellforRowAtIndexPath:(UIIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

for fetching the thumbnails lazily. I also added placeholders there for the cells UIImageViews.

```
//lazy loading of thumbnails for images in cell via bg thread
-(void)loadImageForCell:(CustomEditTableViewCell*)theCell withFilepath: (NSString*)filepath{

dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    UIImage (__block *img) = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [[GlobalFunctions sharedGlobalFunctions] imageOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40) fromImage:img];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        theCell.imageView.image = thumbnail;
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IDAsyncImageView.h

```
 //////////////////////////////////////
    IDAsyncImageView.h
 /////////////////////////////////////

        @interface IDAsyncImageView : NSObject

        @property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *cache;    

        + (instancetype)instance;

        - (void)loadImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView withURLString:(NSString *)urlString;

        @end

    //////////////////////////////////////
    IDAsyncImageView.m
    /////////////////////////////////////

        #import "IDAsyncImageView.h"



            @implementation IDAsyncImageView

                + (instancetype)instance
                {
                    static IDAsyncImageView *_instance = nil;
                    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
                    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
                        _instance = [[self alloc] init];
                });
                return _instance;
            }

        - (instancetype)init
        {
            self = [super init];
            if (self) {
                self.cache =  [[NSCache alloc] init];
            }

            return self;
        }

        - (void)loadImageView:(UIImageView*)imageView withURLString:(NSString *)urlString
        {
            UIActivityIndicatorView* activityView;
            activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            activityView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
            activityView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, imageView.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
            activityView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
            [imageView addSubview:activityView];
            [activityView startAnimating];

            UIImage* imageLoad = [self.cache objectForKey:urlString];
            if (nil != imageLoad) {
                imageView.image = imageLoad;
                [activityView removeFromSuperview];
            }
            else {

            // Block variable to be assigned in block.
            __block NSData *imageData;

            // Dispatch a background thread for download
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
                imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
                UIImage* imageLoad = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                // Update UI on main thread
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    [self.cache setObject:imageLoad forKey:urlString];
                    imageView.image = imageLoad;
                    [activityView removeFromSuperview];
                });
            });
            }
        }

    //////////////////////////////////////
    ViewController.m
    //////////////////////////////////////

        - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[IDAsyncImageView instance] loadImageView:myImageView withURLString:aUrl];
        }
```