# Display Image fetched from the WebService

Tags: ios, web-services, uiimageview

How to display an Image in the ImageView which is fetched from the WebService?

I am able to retrieve the Name of the image from the service successfully, but unable to set the image in the ImageView

```
NSString *imgName = [students objectForKey:@"Image"];
NSLog(@"%@", imgName); **/* Image1.png */**
imgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
```

NSLog gives following output on Console :

> Image1.png

I am unable to set the image in the ImageView

Comment: Do you have this name image added in your project?

Comment: You have to check whether that image is added to target or not

Comment: `imgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];`
this statement will only display the image if it is already added in the project. I assume that the image is not still downloaded on your device. so might be the image will be fetched like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318471/loading-images-in-background-to-optimize-the-loading-in-ios/17318655#17318655

Comment: @Anuj : No, I an retrieving that Image Name from Sequel Pro via WebServices

Comment: @VNJ : You have image name only, you cannot draw image by it's image name, Ask for image url instead of image name to your server end developer and use that url to download image

Comment: @Anuj : Can you please share a sample Code for Image URL

Comment: @VNJ already shared the link for downloading and showing images from a url see above

Comment: @VNJ :Dude are you asking sample code for downloading image from image url?

Comment: @Anuj : Yes, I am asking the same

Comment: @VNJ: Use this NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL STRING"]];
    UIImage*image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

Comment: @Anuj : Not getting the image in the UIImage :(

Comment: @Anuj : On debugging, getting nil

Comment: @VNJ :Do you pass the image url string?, if yes and still not getting image then try that url in browser and check if this url has an image or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SDWebImage :

```
    // Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

This is the link for download and how to use it:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: My URL receives JSON string

Comment: You should receive the complete url with a format like http://example.com/image1.png or you should constitute the hole link by appending the base url to your imgName string:
NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,[students objectForKey:@"Image"]]

Answer (score 0):

You can also  use this code set image

```
cell.img.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your url"]]]];
```